# Few users with equal amount in a bounty question

Tags: support, bounty

Recently I've answered a bounty question. After 7 days period answers was not awarded. When grace period ended I and other user had an equal amount. Other user was awarded (half bounty amount) by system. So I'm just curious: by what criteria the system selects the winner, if few users have the same number of votes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

> If two or more eligible answers have the same score (i.e., their scores are tied), the oldest answer is awarded the bounty.

Comment: Wow... sorry, I missed this. Thank you.